# Is there any way to make this drag&drop to drag&rearrange/reorder instead?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm experimenting with drag & drop which works fine, here is a sketch.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".drag-container");
const template = `
<div draggable="true" class="draggable-box">
  <div class="component draggable" id="%id%">
    <button>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb"></i>
    </button>
    <span>%name%</span>
  </div>
</div>`;
var items,dragSrcEl,currentlyOveredItem;

const fillDragContainer = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let friendlyIndex = i+1;
        let html = template.replace("%id%", `comp_${friendlyIndex}`).replace("%name%", `Name ${friendlyIndex}`);
        container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    }
    addEventsToElements();
}

const handleDragStart = function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '0.4';
    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}

const handleDragEnd = function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '1';
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        item.classList.remove('over');
    });
}

const handleDragOver = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

const handleDragEnter = function(e) {
    currentlyOveredItem = this;
    removeOverClassFromEveryItem();
    this.classList.add('over');
}

const handleDragLeave = function(e) {
    if( this == currentlyOveredItem ){ return; }
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

const handleDrop = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.

    if (dragSrcEl !== this) {
        dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
}

const removeOverClassFromEveryItem = function(){
    items.forEach(function(item){
        item.classList.remove('over');
    });
}

const addEventsToElements = function () {
    items = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable-box");
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
        item.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
        item.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
        item.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
        item.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
        item.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
    });
}

const removeEvents = function(){
    items.forEach(function(item){
        item.removeEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
        item.removeEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
        item.removeEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
        item.removeEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
        item.removeEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
        item.removeEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
    });
}

fillDragContainer();
```

```css
.components{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(58px, 1fr));
    align-content: baseline;
    gap: 2em;
    padding: 10px;
}

.component{
  gap: 5px;
  max-width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  padding: 10px;
  
  text-align:center;
  
  cursor: grab;
}

.component:hover{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.component button{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a26f6e4ee4.js"></script>
<div class="components drag-container">
    
</div>
```

On codepen: https://codepen.io/drrandom/pen/VwqYmQa?editors=1011

I wonder if i could make it so it does not replace the draggable component when i drop it but to rearrange the entire div's content and just drops it in place. So like a sortable list of some kind.

Something like this codepen: https://codepen.io/siniger/pen/gOLmrob but without any third party library and in a grid system.

Answer (score 0):

So i have partially solved the problem. It isn't elegant at all yet but it works. I just need to create a library like code from this to be able to standarize it and make it more robust and clean.

The idea is that if i drag over an element i will insert an empty container before it.Remove the previous empty containers on new drag over events and place the dragged element to the empty container on drop. That way all the other elements are pushed because i inserted a new empty container.

```
const container = document.querySelector(".drag-container");
const template = `
<div draggable="true" class="draggable-box">
  <div class="component draggable" id="%id%">
    <button>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-lightbulb"></i>
    </button>
    <span>%name%</span>
  </div>
</div>`;
const emptyTemplate = `
<div id="empty-drag-element" draggable="true" class="draggable-box">
  
</div>`;

var items,dragSrcEl,currentlyOveredItem,lastDraggedOverElement;

const fillDragContainer = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let friendlyIndex = i+1;
        let html = template.replace("%id%", `comp_${friendlyIndex}`).replace("%name%", `Name ${friendlyIndex}`);
        container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    }
    addEvents();
}

const handleDragStart = function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '0.4';
    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}

const handleDragEnd = function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '1';
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        item.classList.remove('over');
    });
}


const handleDragOver = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let draggedOverElement = e.target.closest(".draggable");
    if( lastDraggedOverElement == draggedOverElement ){ return; }
    lastDraggedOverElement = draggedOverElement;
    addEmptyTemplate(lastDraggedOverElement);
    return false;
}

var lastEmptyTemplate;
const addEmptyTemplate = function(element){
    if( !element ){return;}
    removeEmptyTemplate();
    element = element.closest(".draggable-box");
    //console.log("Adding empty element before", element);
    element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", emptyTemplate);
    lastEmptyTemplate = document.querySelector("#empty-drag-element");
    //console.log("lastEmptyTemplate", lastEmptyTemplate);
    addEvents();
}

const removeEmptyTemplate = function(){
    if( !lastEmptyTemplate ){ return; }
    console.log("Removing empty template", lastEmptyTemplate);
    lastEmptyTemplate.remove();
    lastEmptyTemplate = null;
}

const handleDragEnter = function(e) {
    currentlyOveredItem = this;
    removeOverClassFromEveryItem();
    this.classList.add('over');
}

const handleDragLeave = function(e) {
    if( this == currentlyOveredItem ){ return; }
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

const handleDrop = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
    if( !lastEmptyTemplate ){ return; }
    lastEmptyTemplate.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    dragSrcEl.remove();
    lastEmptyTemplate.removeAttribute("id");
    lastEmptyTemplate = "";
    //if (dragSrcEl !== this) {
        //dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        //this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    //}

    return false;
}

const removeOverClassFromEveryItem = function(){
    items.forEach(function(item){
        item.classList.remove('over');
    });
}

const addEvents = function () {
    removeEvents();
    items = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable-box");
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
        item.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
        item.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
        item.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
        item.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
        item.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
    });
}

const removeEvents = function(){
    if( !items ){ return; }
    items.forEach(function(item){
        item.removeEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
        item.removeEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
        item.removeEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
        item.removeEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
        item.removeEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
        item.removeEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
    });
}

fillDragContainer();
```

Here is a more polished version where it will work with dinamically inserted elements.

Just start it with a container and it will track every .draggable-box inside.

```
var container,dragged,overElement,lastEmptyTemplate;
const emptyTemplate = `<div id="empty-drag-element" draggable="true" class="empty-draggable-box"></div>`;

const start = function(_container){
    if( !_container ){ console.warn("Can't start dragger without a container."); return false; }

    container = _container;

    ['dragstart','dragend', 'dragover', 'dragenter', 'dragleave'].forEach( evt => 
        container.addEventListener(evt, function(e){
            let box = e.target.closest(".draggable-box");
            if( !box ){ return; }
            determineEvent(evt,e,box);
        }, false)
    );

    return true;
}

const determineEvent = function(evt,e,box){
    switch(evt){
        case "dragstart":
            dragged = box;
            dragStart(e);
            break;
        case "dragend":
            dragEnd(e);
            break;
        case "dragover":
            dragOver(e);
            break;
        case "dragenter":
            dragEnter(e);
            break;
        case "dragleave":
            dragLeave(e);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function closestEdge(e, elem) {
    if( !elem ){ return "left"; }
    const { left, right } = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    const { pageX } = e;
    const elementWidth = right - left;
    const elementMiddle = left + elementWidth / 2;
    if( pageX < elementMiddle ){ return "left"; }
    if( pageX > elementMiddle ){ return "right"; }
    return "center";
}

const addEmptyTemplate = function(e,side){
    if( !overElement ){return;}
    removeEmptyTemplate();
    //console.log(side)
    if(side == "left"){
        overElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", emptyTemplate);
    }else{
        overElement.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", emptyTemplate);
    }
    lastEmptyTemplate = document.querySelector("#empty-drag-element");
}

const removeEmptyTemplate = function(){
    if( !lastEmptyTemplate ){ return; }
    lastEmptyTemplate.remove();
    lastEmptyTemplate = null;
}

const dragStart = function(e){
    dragged.classList.add("dragging");
}

const dragEnd = function(e){
    dragged.classList.remove("dragging");

    if( !lastEmptyTemplate ){ return; }
    lastEmptyTemplate.innerHTML = dragged.innerHTML;
    dragged.remove();
    lastEmptyTemplate.classList.add("draggable-box");
    lastEmptyTemplate.classList.remove("empty-draggable-box");
    lastEmptyTemplate.removeAttribute("id");
    lastEmptyTemplate = "";
}

const dragOver = function(e){
    let _overElement = e.target.closest(".draggable-box");
    let side = closestEdge(e,_overElement);
    if(!_overElement || _overElement == overElement ){ return; }
    overElement = _overElement;
    addEmptyTemplate(e,side);
}

const dragEnter = function(e){

}

const dragLeave = function(e){

}

export { start }
```